# RabbitMQ .net client 3.4.3 compatibility

Tags: rabbitmq, .net-3.5, compatibility

We have an framework 3.5 app that needs to interact with some RabbitMQ queues

RabbitMQ's .net client 3.4.3 does support framework 3.5, however is quite old, and I want to known if this version of the client can work out as a consumer for RabbitMQ newests versions

Does anyone knows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the 3.4.3 .NET client should work with current RabbitMQ versions. The AMQP protocol has not changed.

The easiest way to verify is to try it out yourself, or, check out the .NET client code at that version and run the tests yourself.

https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/tree/rabbitmq_v3_4_3